# How to boost number in /order_id/375/ URL or how to hide this part in URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, database, url, ce-1.9.2.2

On fronted when customer clicks on "Vew my order" he gets URL like this:
`domain.com/sales/order/view/order_id/375/`

when he clicks on "print order" the URL will be: 
`domain.com/sales/order/print/order_id/375/`

By looking at the "375" people can know the number of actual orders site has.

1. How can I boost that `order_id/375/` to a longer number
   for example `order_id/1537615/`. Where is this info stored in the database?

   or, is it possible to hide this part of URL  (view order  and print order at customer account)
   or do something that will hide the actual amount of orders on site.
2. What file do I need to edit to replace  /order_id/" in that URL  and use a different word instead , for example "/transaction/

I use Magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: Magento checked owner with each order of customer, i think you don't need change `order_id`

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query on your database:

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1537615;
```

this way your next order will have the number `1537615`, the next one `1537616` and so on.
For existing orders the users will still see the old number, but for new ones nobody will know.

Comment: I'd say this is a easy and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

simply overwrite the existing controller and pass the `increment_id` value rather than `order_id` and fetch product by that value.
Overwrite the controllers wherever you want to change the value.

Comment: Thank you for reply! 
At this point I still learning and editing the controller is kinda hard for me. 

Can I simply edit the database and set next "order_id" value to a larger number? 

For example  "order Increment ID" is stored in table called "eav_entity_store"  under  "increment_last_id."  I changed it to a larger number. 

Can I do the same thing for "order_id" ? Thanks

Comment: No ... don't change that, it will create more problems with association.  
I'll give the code ASAP.